# build failed react-native app on emulator unable to resolve class groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine

Tags: react-native

I'm having trouble to run react-native on emulator with npm start and choose for android.
it keep giving me this error. Note that i've made no change since init this project

```
FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* Where:
Script 'D:\reactnative\firstProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle' line: 435

* What went wrong:
Could not compile script 'D:\reactnative\firstProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle'.
> startup failed:
  script 'D:\reactnative\firstProject\node_modules\@react-native-community\cli-platform-android\native_modules.gradle': 435: unable to resolve class groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine
   @ line 435, column 18.
         def engine = new groovy.text.SimpleTemplateEngine()
                      ^
```

I've try react native doctor, read thru some doc but notthing seem to help

Comment: provide gradle folder file gradle-wrapper.properties file screen shot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In above error you need to change in `gradle.wrapper.property` file

```
/android/gradle/wrapper/gradle-wrapper.properties
```

you need to change `distributionUrl`

in my case I was changed `6.2` to `6.3` it's working

```
distributionUrl=https\://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-6.3-all.zip
```

Comment: that actually work, tks a lot. In my case i change the version from 8.0.1 to 8.2 since i cant found gradle distribution for 8.0.1 in gradle distribution doc :https://services.gradle.org/distributions/